How to draw the double perovskite Sr2FeMoO6 by software/hand?
https://tgc.ac.in/pdf/study-material/chemistry/Ionic_Bonding_Sem_II_G.E._and_D.S.C..pdf

"In the structure of the double
perovskite Sr2FeMoO6, MO6 (M = Fe2+, Mo6+) octahedra share all their vertices, and Sr2+ ions fill
the cubooctahedral cavities that are flanked by eight MO6 octahedra.[2] Each O2- ion is
coordinated to one Fe2+ and one Mo6+ ion in order to achieve local electroneutrality, and thus the
FeO6 and MoO6 octahedra alternate in the structure."


Download a CIF or POSCAR and visualize with Vesta or equivalent software! You can get a POSCAR from here: https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-19127 Note, that link also shows a visualization of the structure, but it is rather bad...

Take a look at ref. 2. In the first figure, there is an image of that structure, or follow the advice above.

Converting comments into an answer here.
Just use the structure from mp-19127 as it seems to be the one you are looking for.
Drawing structures by hand generally is best done by finding a template CIF and making replacements followed by some optimization.
